# Clarify and improve Necromancer badge description to match the better-worded Revival

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

The description for the Silver badge [Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) reads like so:

> Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Now, there are two things that I found confusing:

First, is `Answer a question more than 60 days later`. Does this mean that the question must be 60 days old, or does it mean that the question must be inactive (not answered/commented on/edited) for 60 days?

Second, is `with a score of 5 or more`. Is this talking about the score of the answer or the question?

I think this badge can definitely have a clearer description for people who happen to be hunting for it.

Comment: Then you are automatically suggesting to fix https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival in the same manner.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The description for Revival actually seems much better and clearer

Comment: Hmm, I swear it used to use the same phrasing before!

Comment: At least 61 days after the question was asked. The answer has to have a score greater or equal to 5.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev It would be much better if the Necromancer description was similar to Revival

Comment: I'm not strictly against a rephrase, just consider it unnecessary -- i.e. it most probably would not be a strict improvement. If you can think of a better wording, propose it as an answer and let's see how much traction it gets.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Good idea, came up with a new description.

Answer (score 10):

A suggestion for a new wording of the description (changes in bold):

> **Post an answer with a score of 5 or more** to a question more than 60 days **after it was asked**. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Versus the old description:

> Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

> Answer a question more than 60 days later. Does this mean that the question must be 60 days old, or does it mean that the question must be inactive (not answered/commented on/edited) for 60 days?

More than 60 days old. The answer needs to be posted more than 60 days later than the question. "Later" is given without further qualifications, so it must refer to the question's "time" -- i.e. when it was asked.

> with a score of 5 or more. Is this talking about the score of the answer or the question

The answer, of course. It is a badge that *you* get for *your* achievement. The question scoring points is not your achievement but rather its author's.

Theoretically, a badge *could* take the question's score into account but only in conjunction with some qualities of your answer -- your answer has to have some confirmation of its quality to be worthy of a badge!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But, shouldn't the description of the badge itself be clearer as well, so someone will understand just by reading the badge description?

Comment: @JerryD Apart from explanation, I wanted to show that this is quite self-evident from common sense.

Comment: _"I wanted to show that this is quite self-evident from common sense."_ I think for some people this isn't a problem in understanding but the simple fact they use English as a second language and can have some difficulties understanding.